# After query.executeUpdate() hibernate, it is not the updated value when querying before committing

Tags: hibernate

I am trying to update a record in db and before committing the record, I want to see whether the record is updated or not. Unfortunately, its not showing the updated result.

```
public class MainApp {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SessionFactory sessionFactory =HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Employee emp;

        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

        // Get Employee with id
        Query query = session.createQuery("from Employee where id= :id");
        query.setLong("id", 3);
        emp = (Employee) query.uniqueResult();
        System.out.println("Employee ID : " + emp.getId() + " Employee name : " + emp.getName() + " ; Employee Salary : " + emp.getSalary() + " ; Employee City : " + emp.getAddress().getCity());

        // Update Employee
        query = session.createQuery("update Employee set name= :name where id= :id");
        query.setParameter("name", "xyz");
        query.setLong("id", 3);
        int result = query.executeUpdate();
        System.out.println("Employee Update Status=" + result);

        // Get Employee with id
        query = session.createQuery("from Employee where id= :id");
        query.setLong("id", 3);
        emp = (Employee) query.uniqueResult();
        System.out.println("Employee Name=" + emp.getName() + ", City=" + emp.getAddress().getCity());

        // closing hibernate resources
        tx.commit();
        session.close();
        sessionFactory.close();
        System.out.println("Success...");
    }

}
```

In the above code first I am querying the employee with employee id 3, then updating the name of this employee from "abc" to "xyz", then querying the same employee to see whether its name has been updated or not. I am still getting the older name which is "abc".

If hibernate first updates the object locally in cache and finally updates it into db when committing the transaction, then while querying for the same object 2nd time, the same object from local cache should be returned containing the updated value. However this isn't the case.

Answer (score 0):

That is expected. Update queries do not affect in-memory state. Since you already loaded the employee in the session before executing the update query, its state is unaffected.

You need to clear the session, or to stop using update queries: just use

```
emp.setName("xyz");
```

That is all you need to change the name of the employee.

Also note that the select query is also useless. You should just use `session.get()`.